# How to use datetime picker values for accessing data from database using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datetimepicker

I have created a form with two datetime picker and want to access the data stored in Access database between two specific dates selected from datetime picker.

Could some one please help on how to proceed that on click of button

```
    objDoc = gobjGeoApp.document
    Dim GeoApp As GeoMedia.Application
    GeoApp = gobjGeoApp
    objDoc.Close()

    GeoApp.Open("C:\GeoWorkspaces\PowerPOCfinal.gws")

    objDoc.Connections.Add("Connect1")

    With objDoc.Connections.item(1)
        .Location = "C:\Warehouses\prjct_mntrng.mdb"

        .Description = "PM Data"
        .Mode = PClient.ConnectionConstants.gmcModeReadWrite
        .Type = "Access.GDatabase"
        .Connect()
    End With

    With ListBox1
        .Items.Add("Full Name = " & objDoc.Connections(1).Name)
        .Items.Add("Name = " & objDoc.Name)
        .Items.Add("Path = " & objDoc.Path)
        .Items.Add("Storage = " & objDoc.Storage)
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    ' Create and display recordset of Actual Start
    objConnect = objDoc.Connections.item(1)
    objConnect.CreateOriginatingPipe(objOPipe1)

    With objOPipe1
        .GeometryFieldName = "Geometry"
        .Table = "Electric_Cables"
        .Filter = "((Electric_Cables.Actual_Start)<=" + DateTimePicker1.Value.Date() + " And (Electric_Cables.Actual_Start)<=" + DateTimePicker2.Value.Date() + ")"
        objRS = objOPipe1.OutputRecordset
        objRS.MoveLast()
        objRS.MoveFirst()
        MsgBox(objOPipe1.OutputRecordset.RecordCount)

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: do you know how to connect to database from vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

On Button Click do this,I just Bind the Data in Gridview Control as per you requirement use the Data in DataSet

```
  Dim connection As SqlConnection = New sqlconnection()
  connection.ConnectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING"
  connection.Open()
  Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table where Date between DateTimePicker1.Value and DateTimePicker2.Value", connection)
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
  adp.Fill(ds)
  DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: I have access database, so Dim connection as SqlConnection gives and error.please help and also i want to display retireived data in listbox..can u please suggest how to proceed

Comment: is it in runtime or complie time

Comment: compile time error and error is "Type Sql Connection not defined. and i have already connection to database then can i import these connection properties instead of making new coonection

Comment: Use Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Are you used  Imports System.Data.SqlClient if you find the solution plz tell me

Comment: hello i tried using that now when i have specified my connection string as C:\warehoues\eletric_line.mdb it gives an error of format intialization and format specification

Comment: It is saying code too long when i trying to post it

Comment: 1.Could you added the DataBase in server explorer.

Comment: connection.connectionstring:- what i need to specify

Comment: wen i ran the above specified code it gives me errror "No Value given for one or more required parameters" at point of adp.fill(ds)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to concatenate the value from the controls with the rest of the SQL statement, like this:

```
"select * from Table where Date between" + DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString() + " and " + DateTimePicker2.SelectedDate.ToString()
```

You could also consider just adding an ASP SqlDataSource and it will be something like this:

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [mydt], [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE (([mydt] &gt;= ?) AND ([mydt] &lt;= ?))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Calendar1" Name="mydt" PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Calendar2" Name="mydt2" PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```